# DBpedia: Query All information about a specific resource with SPARQL

Tags: sparql

If I have a dbpedia url (i.e., http://dbpedia.org/page/Idris_Elba), how can I query SPARQL to return all dob & foaf information and to verify if the entity (in this case Idris Elba) is a person? true/false

Current Query

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select * { 
  values ?person { dbpedia:Idris_Elba}
  ?person ?p ?o
}
```

Comment: and you tried what? or did you read previous questions here? there was even a related question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686797/dbpedia-query-all-information-about-a-specific-resource-with-sparql

Comment: and `true/false` as return type is what you find when you read the specs for `ASK` queries

Comment: current query added. Iv looked at previous questions.
iv read the ASK spec but wasn't sure how to incorporate this into a SELECT/WHERE Query

Comment: good. and what doesn't work with the query now? you mean the filter of properties by some namespace? This can for example be done via `filter(strstarts(str(?p), str(dbo:)) || strstarts(str(?p), str(foaf:)))`

Comment: and by incorporate `ASK` into `SELECT` you mean what? you want to have a boolean value in the result of the `SELECT` query? then you can make use of the `bind` keyowrd.  if not, what is the problem with the `ASK` query which would be `ASK { dbpedia:Idris_Elba a dbo:Person }`

Comment: So, I would like to return all dbo and foaf details. I have seen you can query by defining each property like name, height, abstract etc. ```?person dbo:Name ?name .```. Also have a Is Person value returned and all returned in a single row

Comment: It's not possible to get all in a single row without knowing the properties in advance. The "columns" are defined by the projection part, i.e. `Select ?s ?p1 ?p2 ...`